# Active windows moved to secondary screen

Tags: 13.04, multiple-monitors

Ok. Help.  I use my 13.04 system frequently when teaching. Everytime I connect the beamer, all the active windows (and desktop files) are moved to the secondary screen. This becomes really annoying after a while, as I am continuously flashing my notes (and anything embarassing I might have open, including, say, personal emails) on the beamer screen.

How can I make sure windows and files remain on the primary screen unless I drag them over to the secondary screen? The displays function in system settings does not solve this problem. Or maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: I experience the same issue on my Linux Ubuntu 14.04.5 running running KDE 4.13.3.

Comment: A related question that was asked later: [Windows move to external monitor at connection](http://askubuntu.com/questions/846777/windows-move-to-external-monitor-at-connection) on 16.04.