# Windows move to external monitor at connection

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, display

When I connect an external monitor to my laptop using HDMI, the windows open on my laptop's display move to the newly connected monitor.

Any idea of what causes this behavior and how to have the windows stay on my laptop's display ?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and Unity.

Thanks

Comment: A related question that was asked earlier: [Active windows moved to secondary screen](http://askubuntu.com/q/296857/323249) on 13.04.